# Package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" is incompatible with structures "all"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add EF Core to a project. By typing in the terminal
`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory --version 6.0`
but doing this I get first error:

`NU1301: Could not load service index for source http://teamcity.monogame.net/guestAuth/app/nuget/feed/_Root/default/v3/index.json.`

I noticed that the name of the MonoGame framework that I used to use is wrong, I removed it which helped, but after trying to add EF Core again, I got another error:

`The package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" is incompatible with the structures "all" in the project "C: \ Users \ user \ PizzaStore1 \ PizzaStore1.csproj".`
I don't know what this means that the package is incompatible with the "all" structure. Please help.